# Symfony form Set Value of non mapped field from database

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a TextType **label** field in my form, my Entity is EAV, 
the structure is : 
id, 
targetId,
entityTargetName,

In my form I have a non mapped field **label** a dynamic  from database,  when rendering my form I must send a query to database with targetId and entityTargetName and get the value of **label** field and set it to the form.

I know that I can do query builder but my field is not a select, it's a TexType

```
        ->add('productName ', TextType::class,
            array(
                'mapped'=>false,
            )
        )
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

You can inject entity repository not just for EntityType field.

You can do the following:
1. Create form in your controller in this way (or something similar):

```
/** @var FormInterface $form */
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(MyFormType::class, null, [
    'action' => $this->get('router')->generate('my_action_routename'),
    'method' => 'POST',
    'entityManager' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(),
]);
```

2. Add configureOptions method to your MyFormType class:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class'    => MyModelClass::class,
        'entityManager' => null, // This is important
    ]);
}
```

3. Use entity manager in this way in your buildForm method and pass it to default value:

```
$options['entityManager']->getRepository(ProductRepository::class)->getProductName(targetId, entityTargetName);
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks a_sarana, but how to get targetId and entityTargetName, my  form is a collection

Comment: @spinoza, maybe you should use Form events? Please see https://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-listener-to-a-form-class.
You may want to use FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA event.

Comment: @spinoza Indeed, FormEvents is better for this in my opinion.